# How to read through an LL parsing ?

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

I read that the LL parser is a Top down parser. So logically I suppose that we read throughout from the top to the down.
However, there's many way for read from the top to the down.
I found on wikipedia a page which talk about the depth first which speak of the course in an tree data structure (binary tree).
Otherwise, there is 3 kind of depth first: Pre-order, In-order, Post-order.
In my mind, I suppose that I need to use the Post-order one but how to be sure ?
how to know which kind of depth first need I to use for the LL parsing ?

depth first : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

There's usually an infinite number of ways to traverse a grammar, just like there's an infinite number of possible inputs that adhere to the grammar.

When you walk the grammar you typically don't do it like you would a traditional tree or graph structure. Rather, your walk is dictated by an input stream of tokens coming from the lexer.

E.g. if you find yourself at a place in the grammar where it has has a production where either an identifier or an integer literal may occur, the branch taken is dictated by whether the current token is one or the other (or something else, which would then be a syntax error for that input).